# Calculate mortgage payment in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I wonder if there is a way to calculate monthly mortgage payment through Pyspark. In other words, if I have total term, 360 for 30 years mortgage, interest rate 4% and loan balance 200000, based on Excel pmt function, the monthly payment will be $954. How can I do this in Pyspark?

I search on line but didn't find a solid solution. Thanks.

Comment: How would you do that calculation in python itself?

Comment: Post example data and  show us what you have tried , if you don't do it you will be downvoted soon

Comment: Don't worry guys. I eventually use this link's solution to calculate it: https://ron.sh/calculating-amortization-with-python/